# Possible to open mail app with search results displayed from app?

Tags: ios, email, messageui

I don't want to write my own email app. All I want is to be able redirect to mail with a preconfigured search string to display relevant emails. There doesn't appear to be a way to read or list emails from mail.app from within another app. Am I overlooking something? Is there a workaround for this?
I am fully aware of and able to use message UI in my app. What I want is to read, not send, email that has already been downloaded and exists in mail.app.

Answer (score 0):

The only way that you can use to connect apps with other apps in iOS is thought url scheme.

You can take a look at [Url Scheme reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/Introduction/Introduction.html)

but it seems like you can't make this action.

**UPDATE:**

you can take a look the extra functionalities at [Wikipedia](http://wiki.akosma.com/IPhone_URL_Schemes#Mail)

Comment: I'd seen most of this in one form or another. I can't find anything to list or read existing emails.